# Not able to find data with id for nodejs api

Tags: node.js, json, api, express

Here is my api data:
[image]

This is how I am fetching data for the specific "customeHashID"

[image]

In the console I am getting, singleID as undefined
[image]

[image]

Kindly help!

Comment: please post code, not images of code ...

Comment: remove the `:` from the request url in the browser. The `:` is just to denote a path parameter in the routing at the backend, you must not add it in the request from the frontend. As you can see in your debuglog, the value for your parameter is `:edu34` but the hashvalue in the object is `edu34` ...

Comment: Your browserurl has value `edu64`. Is There any object with that value in your array?

Answer (score 0):

Try just using this in the url of the browser:

```
localhost:3233/edu64
```

You should remove the ":" from the ":edu64"